# Use RxJava in queue-like manner and pause/start queue

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to use RxJava in my Android application, along with Retrofit, to interact with a  RESTful API.

In my Android app I sent out a number of requests at various UX events. If one of the request returns an 'Invalid Token' error, I want to pause any other requests that get queued before they start so that I can renew the user's token, and then resume the paused requests.

Is this possible using RxJava? I'm just learning the library and am having trouble finding this functionality.

Thanks,

Comment: I have a vague idea about how I'd do it, but I can't make it a proper answer. What if the first thing each queued request does is get the user token from an observable, and you set up that observable so you can invalidate the token and make it obtain a new one?

Answer (score 0):

If these requests are sent in parallel, then you will likely get multiple "Invalid Token" errors. You would want to refresh the token for only the first instance of the error. To pause requests while the token is being refreshed, think about the source of the valid token being an observable.

Let's assume you have a network handling class that has methods:

```
Single<Response> makeNetworkRequest(Request request) { ... }
Single<Boolean> getToken() { ... }
```

It is implemented such that a value is emitted when a token is available, but otherwise waits until the token is refreshed.

Then, your observer chain will look something like:

```
observerChain
  .flatMapSingle(request -> networkHandler.makeNetworkRequest(request)
       .retryWhen(error -> error.flatMapSingle(e -> networkHandler.getToken()))
  ...
```

The `retryWhen()` operator recovers from the error by providing an observable that, when non-empty, will resubscribe to the upstream observable, in this case, the `makeNetworkRequest()`.

Since you don't show any of your code that you are trying to adapt, you will have to make adjustments to the code above to get it to work with your application.